# Vectors: How do I check each element to see if it equals a user input?

Tags: java

Basically this is what I have:

```
if(field1.getText().equals("")){
        label2.setForeground(Color.red);
        label2.setText("Please enter a pet type");
    }
    else if(field1.getText().equals(petList.get(z)){
        label2.setForeground(Color.red);
        label2.setText("The pet type already exists");
    }
    else{
        label2.setForeground(Color.red);
        label2.setText("Pet Type Added");
    String input = field1.getText();
    petList.add(j,input);
    j++;
    }
```

What I need to do is check field1 to see if it equals any of the elements in the vector petList. How can I accomplish this? I have already tried using a for loop on the outside of the if loop like this :`for(int z = 0; z < petList.size(); z++){` but it returned an array index out of range error. Any help would be awesome! I would prefer to do it using the same basic structure that I have now, but if it can't be done that's ok. This code is inside of a buttonlistener class, if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Did you look at the contains method in Vector. petList.contains(field1.getText())

Answer (score 0):

Without revealing the solution (and thereby not giving you the chance to develop your skills) here is a tip!

You could use a for-each loop.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

And for every iteration check if the element at the current location in the array equals the users input.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
if(field1.getText().equals(""))
```

with

```
if (contains(vect, field1.getText()))
```

and put the following method:

```
private static boolean contains(Vector v, String s) {
     for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
         if (s.equals((String) v.elementAt(i))) {
            return true;
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct, you are getting array index out of range error in line  `petList.add(j,input);` Instead of specifying the index, why dont you add this input after the for loop using `petList.add(input);`